# Issue with Referenced DLL's on compiled EXE in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll

I've written and compiled a DLL in VS2008.  I've created a windows form project to test the DLL.  I've added a reference to my DLL and added it to the project as a link.  I have "using myDLL;" in the form.  I can use the DLL classes and methods perfectly fine in the VS2008 environment, and running the Debug or Release versions work as intended.

However, I'm testing how deployment would work, but anytime I try to load the created EXE it won't load.  I've made sure to stick a copy of the DLL in the folder with the EXE but it still fails to load.  It's strange because it doesn't even throw an error message, it just stops working and closes.  I haven't ever used assemblies before, but it was my understanding that they were unnecessary if you had references to them in the project?  How can I get the EXE to work outside of the VS2008 environment?

Comment: What does the Windows Event Log say?

Comment: @noMad17  They seem to indicate a System.IO.FileNotFoundException but there's no useful details in the event properties.

Comment: I see, where is your reference pointing? Have you set CopyLocal = true?

Comment: The reference is pointing to the project folder that contains the assembled DLL, but I have CopyLocal set to true so I figured it'd drag it along?  That's also why I added the DLL to the project as a link because previously I had similar issues but that resolved them, but it doesn't seem to be helping here.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that the .dll is being copied to your output directory but the application crashes immediately when you run the .exe... Is your executable still in the output folder when you run it or have you moved it somewhere?

Comment: I just looked and even though I have "Copy Local = true", the DLL is not being copied over.  I just put the copy of the DLL in to the same folder as the application and it ran fine.  Wonder why it wasn't copied over?

Comment: Could it be that even though you've changed the value in your graphical view the value has not actually been set? You could either look at the project file in a text editor and look for the value there. Or try to change the value back and forth and see if it sticks.

Comment: In an ItemGroup it shows the DLL being added as a reference with SpecificVersion set to false and a HintPath provided to where the DLL is located in it's own project folder.  Later on when I copied the DLL from a folder I had on my desktop, it has another ItemGroup where a content item links directly to the DLL file and just gives a link of the DLL filename.  Could there be an issue with including it both ways?  I have it working, I'm just wondering for future reference.  Also no mention of copying the DLL as far as I can tell.